# How to add search bar in navigation bar for iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to add search bar in navigation bar for iPhone? right now I added to table view?

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 7 it's very easy.  Simply add this to your `UISearchDisplayController`

```
searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

Comment: Hey, kinda great, but my search bar is displayed in the middle of the screen.. and not in the navigation bar.

Comment: @VanDuTran - the only way I can see that happening is if you have left over code somewhere in your class that modifies the positioning of the search bar.  I've used this in a couple apps targeting iOS 7 and this works fine.  See the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html

Comment: @VanDuTran I had the same problem and fixed it by creating an outlet from the NavigationBar titleView to the SearchBar in IB. You can also do it programmatically with  << self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar; >>. Also, I had to reset the tableView contentInset top by -44 to fix the visible white space where the search bar existed.

Comment: @lm2s I have a follow up question about doing this in the IB, will you please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808818/how-to-add-uisearchbar-to-navigationbar-through-the-storyboard-in-ios