# How to add search bar in navigation bar for iphone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add serach bar in navigation bar for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350681/how-to-add-serach-bar-in-navigation-bar-for-iphone)

This is the code to display search bar but i want to put this in navigation bar

```
sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,320,30)];

sBar.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:sBar];
//[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem addSubview:sBar];
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=sBar;
```

is there any way?

Comment: You've already got another couple questions up which ask the same thing.

Answer (score 24):

Add the search bar as title view to the navigation bar. This code example also includes a fix for the extra padding you get by adding it as a title view.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
searchBarView.autoresizingMask = 0;
searchBar.delegate = self;
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
```

Comment: i did same thing but earler i made and IBoutlet of serachbar that was wroking fine but that was scrolling so using your code my serach function is not working ?? how to solve that i think i needt to omit delgate from Iboutlet  what you suggest??

i am geetin a waring if i use this  searchBara.delegate = self;
rootviewCnt doest not impalement UIseachbar delegate protocol

Comment: I have the problem that the results are shown in a table view embedded in a popover, instead of in the frame of the original table view. Any solution to this?

Comment: This seems like a good answer. Where would I place this code? If I copy and paste it into a method called `addSearchBarToNavigationBar`. Where would I call the method? I am using a TableViewController

Answer (score 5):

you can assign any view to the titleView property of the navigation item . You can do it this way .

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar ;
```

This should work out or not then adding search bar to the UIView instance and then assigning this view to self.navigationItem.titleView will do .

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom view for the title section of a navigation bar. Take a look at the [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and especially the Updating the NavigationBar section.

> The navigation controller updates the
>   middle of the navigation bar as
>   follows:
>
> If the new top-level view controller
>   has a custom title view, the
>   navigation bar displays that view in
>   place of the default title view. To
>   specify a custom title view, set the
>   titleView property of the view
>   controller’s navigation item.

Comment: i did this  self.navigationItem.titleView = sBar;  its working but my search () is not working  
i did this bsBar.delegate = self;  now am i missing anything else

Comment: On iPad With this the results are shown in a popover instead of in the original table view area. Any solution to this?