# How to add UISearchBar to NavigationBar through the storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I find what seems like an elegant answer to this question at [How to add search bar in navigation bar for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350681/how-to-add-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-for-iphone) (one question-one answer: very short so please look).

I like the piece about doing it in the storyboard (aka IB): i.e. "create an outlet from the NavigationBar titleView to the SearchBar in IB". But where would I place the SearchBar on the storyboard?

Here is what I did:

- I dropped the SearchBar in my TableView header
- Then from NavigatorBar I point outlet to the SearchBar as titleView (the only option)
- But when I run the program I get a crash: `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

The program also opened my code in

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MINAppDelegate class]));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

just  drag a  View (UIView) into navigation bar, then you can drag almost any UI element inside the view, including UISearchBar. I tried it and works for me.

Comment: The problem about this is that you can not use the whole space in the Tab Bar to place the search bar. You can only use a specific area of it