# Why Can't I add a UISearchBar to a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Why can't I drag a UISearchBar into a UINavigationBar in my Storyboard? I can drag in the UISearchBar but I can't add it as a subview. I've seen plenty of posts where people have done this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first adding a UIView to your navigationbar and then add the searchbar, as previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808818/how-to-add-uisearchbar-to-navigationbar-through-the-storyboard-in-ios). Good Luck.

[image: example]

Comment: Using that configuration I can't get the search bar to span across the top.

Comment: Do you mean you can't make the searchbar the same width or height as the navigationbar?

Comment: No I mean setting It up as a navigation item doesn't let me make my necessary auto layout constraints

Comment: The best I can suggest is to set the 'titleView' of your navigationitem to your searchbar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar, if you go with this approach you should programmatically create your searchbar. If you give me an image of what you're trying to achieve, I can try help you more.